# Extremely weird error when trying to compile file

Tags: c++

Error:

[image: Error when trying to compile]

Link since you cant make the image bigger when its embeded: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhUCp.png

I have no idea what the issue is. Ive never seen the formatting used before either so i posted a screen shot.

Including entire code because i have no idea were the error is. I have nothing else to add to the question but the system thinks i do. What else could i possibly add?

```
#include <iostream>     //Basic input/output
#include <iomanip>      //Manipulators
#include <string>       //String stuff 
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void instruct ();       //Function declaration for printing instructionstring studname ();
void input (ifstream &infile, float& test1, float& test2, float& test3, float& test4, float& test5, float& test6, float& test7, float& test8, float& test9, float& test10, string& studentname);      //Function declaration for input
float aver (float test1, float test2, float test3, float test4, float test5, float test6, float test7, float test8, float test9, float test10);      //Function declaration for calculating average
void output (string studentname, float average);      //Function declaration for output



int main()
{
  float test1 = 0;              //Vars (test1 - test10) for test scores
  float test2 = 0;
  float test3 = 0;
  float test4 = 0;
  float test5 = 0;
  float test6 = 0;
  float test7 = 0;
  float test8 = 0;
  float test9 = 0;
  float test10 = 0;
  string studentname = "a";     //Define Var for storing students name
  float average = 0;            //Define var for storing average


  instruct();     //Function call to print instructions


  ifstream infile("grades.dat");

  input (infile, test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, test8, test9, test10, studentname);     //Function call for scores

  while (!infile.eof())
    {
      average = aver (test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, test8, test9, test10);    //Function call for average

      output (studentname, average);     //Function call for output

      cin.ignore(1);

      input (infile, test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, test8, test9, test10, studentname); //Get new input
    }     //end eof

  return 0;
}

/***************************************************/
/* Name: instruct                                  */
/* Description: Print instructions to user.        */
/* Paramerters: N/A                                */
/* Return Value: N/A                               */
/***************************************************/

void instruct()
{
  cout << "\n" << "This program will calculate the average of 10 test scores that you input. " << "\n" << "\n";
  //Prints instructions

  return;
}

/***************************************************/
/* Name: input                                     */
/* Description: Get input                          */
/* Paramerters: N/A                                */
/* Return Value: N/A                               */
/***************************************************/

void input (float& test1, float& test2, float& test3, float& test4, float& test5, float& test6, float& test7, float& test8, float& test9, float& test10, string& studentname, ifstream& infile)

{
  infile >> studentname;
  infile >> test1 >> test2 >> test3 >> test4 >> test5 >> test6 >> test7 >> test8 >> test9 >> test10;
  infile.ignore(10, '\n');

  return;
}



/***************************************************/
/* Name: aver                                      */
/* Description: Calculate Average                  */
/* Paramerters: N/A                                */
/* Return Value: aver                              */
/***************************************************/


float aver (float test1, float test2, float test3, float test4, float test5, float test6, float test7, float test8, float test9, float test10)

{
  float aver = 0;
  aver = test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 + test5 + test6 + test7 + test8 + test9 + test10;
  aver = aver / 10;
  return aver;
}


/***************************************************/
/* Name: output                                    */
/* Description: Calculate Average                  */
/* Paramerters: N/A                                */
/* Return Value: aver                              */
/***************************************************/

void output (string studentname, float average)      //Function declaration for output
{ 

  cout << studentname;

  cout << average;

  return;
}
```

File being read from:

```
Number One
99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99
John Doe
90 99 98 89 87 90.2 87 99 89.3 91
Clark Bar
67 77 65 65.5 66 72 78 62 61 66
Scooby Doo
78 80 77 78 73 74 75 75 76.2 69
Santa Clause
89 92.5 94 95 91 89 88 90 92 91
Jessie James
45 54 55 56 66 61 65.6 67 43 54
Clara Barton
87 88 76 75.7 80 88 83 84 85 81.2
Alex Mack
55 65 66.5 67 76 77.7 66 67.8 71 70
Ann Apolis
87 88 88 88 88 85.4 81 82 89 81
Stewart Mouse
90 92 93 94 95 96 97 97.7 98 99
Sue Sloan
88.5 67.7 88.8 99.9 90.9 89 87 78 89 88
Luke Skywalker
76.7 77.8 88.8 76.7 77 88 87 86 85 80.9
Harry Potter
80 83 84 85 86 79.4 78.5 81 80 82
Mary Poppins
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
Last One
33 44 55 66 77 88 99 22 11 91
```

Comment: Please try to copy and paste error code instead of a screen shot

Comment: Love your function declarations. Err sarcasm off, I wouldn't pass that many parameters to a function, it is a) unsightly and b) easy to mess up. I would probably encapsulate it in a struct/class.

Comment: The program will be more readable and flexible if you pass around stl::vectors rather than hardcoding 10 input/output variables. I think it will get you better grades too.

Comment: Oh also, I think your Putty is misinterpreting some highlighting leading to confusing error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameters list for the input function don't match. You've changed the order between the top version and the bottom.

The bottom one should be:

`void input ( ifstream& infile, float& test1, float& test2, float& test3, float& test4, float& test5, float& test6, float& test7, float& test8, float& test9, float& test10, string& studentname)`

Comment: given this is homework, I think it's inappropriate to just give OP the answer.  When we do that, we end up doing their homework for them, and it doesn't help them to learn.

Comment: Normally, I'd agree, however he's made a good attempt at actually doing the homework, so one minor piece of help is okay.

Answer (score 2):

You declared a function `input(ifstream &, float &, ...)`, but then never defined it and, of course, the compiler can't find it. Perhaps the function `input(float&, ...)` was meant to be the one missing?

By the way, it would be more elegant to use a vector or something similar to pass the data. This would make the code more general (as of now it only works for exactly 10 numbers to be read).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error `undefined symbol` means that you have declared something and tried to use it somewhere in your code, but you haven't defined it.

Given this is homework, I'm not going to spoon-feed the answer to you, but make you work for it.  I will give you  a hint though.  The error message is complaining about a function named `input`.  There is a declaration for something named `input`, and I see there's also a definition for something named `input`.  Are they the same?  Take a closer look.